# I edit the style sheet of my css in wordpress but the changes do not apply on the blog

Tags: wordpress

I'm breaking my head, to change the size of my wordpress blog logo, because they say it is for the css style sheet, but any changes I make to the style sheet do not apply to my blog, even if I delete all style sheet my blog does not change, can anyone help me?

Comment: Check if you have cleared your cache. Also check if you are editing correct css file

Comment: I hope you are editing style.css at root level of your active Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

### There are several things to consider:

1. If the changes you want to make are minor, just use theme editors css and js injection mechanics.
2. Second most common thing is syntax, to counter that just edit your current active themes style file and enter something like `body background-color:{ red !important}` to check if the changes are being made. Then check with your browsers developer tools to check if the changes are being made in the style file.
3. If you are using some caching plugin, turn it off until you are done working on the site changes.
4. Check if you are editing the right theme. You should check what theme is active in your themes section of the wordpress.
5. In the case where you are using a child theme and you are editing child themes style.css file, you should first enqueue the file. More info on that [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)
6. If you are hosting your website not on the shared hosting, but on private server, you should check your file permissions.

Hope this helps.